# Windows 10 update failed on VeraCrypt encrypted volume

Tags: windows-10, encryption, hard-drive-recovery, veracrypt

I tried to update to the latest Windows feature update. After the first restart cycle my VeraCrypt password query didn't show up, the computer completely shut down. Upon restarting manually I couldn't load into Windows due to hard drive problems that it could not diagnose.

I ran command prompt from Advanced Options and found that my C: volume (where Windows is installed) was RAW. I also tried resetting Windows completely and resetting keeping files, both failed. 
I'm now using Ubuntu which I have dual-booted on my machine.

Any recommendations to at least recover some files?

Comment: Sounds like time to just wipe it & restore from your backup.

Comment: You should have decrypted your drive before you installed the update even BitLocker protection is suspended before a feature update is installed. There isn’t a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

> Any recommendations to at least recover some files?

Backups.

Recovery of data from a partially overwritten encrypted volume is likely to be either impossible or to take the sort of forensic skills, dedication and time (or money) that most of us lack.

A typical definition of data security encompasses three major ideas:

- Confidentiality
- Integrity
- Availability

I recommend, when taking measures to address the first or second of these, to also take measures to address the third.

Comment: It's not necessarily overwritten, it may just be detected as raw because the partitioning tool (Disk Management?) doesn't recognize VC's container. Or at least it was before resetting etc. which could have made things worse.

Comment: @gronostaj: This is true, and other answers may provide a recommendation more in line with OP's expectations (especially if OP edits more details into their question) - however I think my recommendation is an important one that can take the stress out of these sort of situations and which is worth bearing in mind prior to undertaking any operation of this nature.